# jQuery: Get title and href values as variables

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a list of links with a title and a href value. I would like to be able to get these values seperately, but I always get the first link's values. Why is that?
[See my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FaNdV/). As you can see - when clicking a any of the link, you always get the values from the first link. I guess setting these variables isn't sufficient:

```
var title = $('.mg_phones').attr('title');
var url = $('.mg_phones').attr('href');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to refer to the clicked element:

```
var title = $(this).attr('title');
var url = $(this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the code to this:

```
var title = $(this).attr('title').toLowerCase();
var url = $(this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)` instead. The issue was that `$('.mg_phones')` is an array of all elements with that class and accessing `$('.mg_phones').attr(...)` would pick the first element as it doesn't know which of them you want.

But `$(this)` refers to the currently clicked item in this context.

```
$('.mg_phones').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = $(this).attr('title').toLowerCase(); //this changed
    var url = $(this).attr('href');  //this changed
      if (title.length != 0) {
          $('#test').text(title + ": " + url);
 }
```