# Getting title from href in a div class

Tags: html, href, title

I am having trouble getting the title from within a div class called swatch so that I can pass it onto a add to basket button ultimately.

Below is the Div class:

```
<h4>Choose a Color:</h4>
<div class="swatch">
<a rel="0,255,0" href="#mask" class="scp" title="Green">Single Colour Green </a>
<a rel="255,255,0" href="#mask" class="scp" title="Yellow">Yellow</a>
<a rel="255,85,15" href="#mask" class="scp" title="Orange">Orange</a>
<a rel="0,0,255" href="#mask" class="scp" title="Blue">Blue</a>
<a rel="155,0,255" href="#mask" class="scp" title="Purple">Purple</a>
<a rel="255,0,0" href="#mask" class="scp" title="Red">Red</a>
</div>
```

Here is the script that I cannot get top work for me:

```
div id="cp"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var title = $(this).attr('title');

  if (title.length != 0) {
      $('#cp').text(title);
  }
setTimeout(function () {
    // Run function with var title
    //window.location = url;
}, 2000);
});
</script>
```

I am using a mixture of code from these two sources....

http://sandbox.nikorablin.com/productColorizer/

&

[jQuery: Get title and href values as variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315193/jquery-get-title-and-href-values-as-variables)

For the moment I just want to display that having changed the colour of image I have that I also get some text displaying the title underneath.

Ultimately I want to pass the title to a 'add to basket' button on a sales page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked your example and it worked fine. When I tried to implement it into my site, it fell apart. I think part of the problem is that my page is using a function that makes my div class swatch appear as blocks of colour not text words.

Demo of what I did:  http://jsfiddle.net/GLCub/2/

Answer (score 1):

I asume that you need to get the title attr from the anchor that was 'clicked', in that case you need to bind to the click event of the anchors and then inside that handler you `$(this).attr('title')` will get you the correct thing. Something like:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#cp').text(title);
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to 'pre-process' your anchors to say use the title attr as a class or color in another element, you can first get all the anchors in the page (say all anchors that have a title attribute) and do the same:

```
$('a[title]').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#cp').addClass(title); // not sure what you want to do here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes |I need the title attr, but the anchor is a function that produces a coloured block corresponding to the title name ie, green, blue, red etc. When I tried this code it appeared to do nothing. Is this because its not a link as such? You really need to goto http://sandbox.nikorablin.com/productColorizer/ to understand what I am attempting as I'm not explaining myself very well.

Comment: Not completely sure I understand what you're trying to do (the page you're referring to has several pieces of functionality, not sure what part are you having trouble with), but see my edit if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
  var title = $(this).attr('title');

  if (title.length != 0) {
  $('#cp').text(title);
 }
 setTimeout(function () {
// Run function with var title
//window.location = url;
}, 2000);
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/ggbhat/GLCub/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I checked out your code and it worked for your example but when I tried to move it across, it wouldn't work. I have made a comment above ans Stack Overflow wont let me post for another 8 hours.